# How to give different styles for each level in treeview in windows phone 8.1?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I have used WinRTXamlToolkit to implement my treeview, it works fine the problem is i want to show differnt font size and font style for each level, and i tried binding the font size from model class but my model class contains list of its own class so i cant find the leve1 over there as well, could any one help me to fix my issue, thanks in advance :)
my xaml code and screenshot is below.

```
     <XC:TreeView                                             
                 Margin="-5,0,0,0"
                 VerticalAlignment="Top"
                 ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TreeViewItemStyle1}"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding ObjShopItems}"> 


        <XC:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
               <Grid>
                  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                       <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />                                                   
                  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                  <TextBlock 
                         Grid.Column="0"
                 FontSize="{StaticResource TextStyleExtraLargeFontSize}"
                 Text="{Binding Name}"
                 TextWrapping="Wrap" />                                                                                            
                  </Grid>

            <XCDATA:DataTemplateExtensions.Hierarchy>
                <XCDATA:HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" />                                                
                </XCDATA:DataTemplateExtensions.Hierarchy>
               </DataTemplate>
         </XC:TreeView.ItemTemplate>

         <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
           <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
           <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=TreeviewCommand}" />
           </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
      </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
      </XC:TreeView>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: @user3956566: hi, i have arranged the code :)

Comment: Could you please answer your question by posting the code? Thx would be grateful